# Problem with centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to center one `item` in a list without centering the list number.

```
\section*{Redovisning}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  \begin{equation}
        f(x) = x(x-2)\end{equation}
    \vspace{0.3cm}  
    \begin{equation}
        g(x) = x(2-x)\end{equation}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \item {$\frac{8}{3}$ a.e.}
    \item  \begin{equation}
    \int\limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
    \end{equation}
    \vspace{0.3cm}      
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
```

Everything looks fine except the `\item {$\frac{8}{3}$ a.e.}`. Everything I have tried have either centered all or have removed the item number.

Comment: Hi, welcomme, please give a fully compileable code.

Comment: You mention "Everything I have tried…". What would some of those things be?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to center one item in a list without centering the list number.

Judging by the remainder of your example code, I will assume that you not only wish to center-set the term `$\frac{8}{3}$ a.e.` but also wish to (a) typeset it in display math mode and (b) to display it on a line by itself. If these assumptions are correct, I suggest you use an unnumbered display-math group, starting with `\[` and ending with `\]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % remove "demo" 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section*{Redovisning}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  
        \begin{align}
        f(x) &= x(x-2)\\
        g(x) &= x(2-x)
        \end{align}
    \item
        \[
        \frac{8}{3}\ \text{a.e.}
        \]
    \item  
        \begin{equation}
        \int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
        \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked great! And your assumptions are correct =) Thanks!

Comment: @Kenny If Mico's answer helped you, you should accept it by clicking the green tick mark at the left of the answer.